# R multilevel analysis: my sample size (gender) is unequal

Tags: r, sample-size, multilevel-analysis

i'm currently working on a mutlilevel anaylsis for my assignment. I am new to R and hope that someone can help me out. I did a survey to collect the data I need. I have 184 participants, where approximately 59 are men and 125 women. It has to be a multilevel analysis because its a diary study (it happens that one ID appears 5times for 5 Days).

I tested some models and the results are always show that women are more emotional than men. So my question is; is that because I have more women in my survey than men, or does R weight them on his own without me having to do anything?

I think the problem is not that the classes are imbalanced per se, its more that there may not be sufficient patterns belonging to the minority class to adequately represent its distribution....

Do unequal sample sizes play a role for multilevel analysis? If so, can anybody help me out with this problem?

Comment: In addition to Peter Flom's answer, I might add that might want to look into the concept of least-squared means, which are treatment "means" adjusted for the effect of other terms in the model.  These are useful to look at or report when observations are unbalanced.  I don't know if they will be useful in your case. A simple example is here: [Webpage](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_05.html).  R has a package `lsmeans` but you will need to check to see if the package will handle well the model you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Multilevel models (like regression models) can deal appropriately with unequal sample sizes. It is very common that the independent variables are not evenly distributed.

I don't know what

> I think the problem is not that the classes are imbalanced per se, its
>   more that there may not be sufficient patterns belonging to the
>   minority class to adequately represent its distribution....

means.

Comment: I think that the answer to the second problem is that anything which relies on the main effect of sex and its interaction with time (which i suspect is what is meant here by pattern) is going to be imprecisely estimated as the number f men goes down.

Comment: yes. How can I tell R that the gender variable is imbalanced (more men than women) or does R know that?

Comment: R knows.  You don't have to explicitly tell it.